# Some specific Special Characters are getting blocked in my server

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I have a problem with my LIVE Server IIS, which I am not facing in my local server IIS.  The characters like '|| ||' are getting blocked in my server, when those are present in any textboxes.  The server is allowing if the single character is present '|'.  Unable to find the correct reason for this.  Only if the above specified characters are present in any of the text boxes in the page, then page redirection is not happening. Can any one has already faced this problem, please help me in solving this.  If I remove the characters from text boxes, then the page redirections are happening perfectly.

EDIT :

The page from client side is not going to server side, in a single shot the button events are getting blocked and not working.  After removing the above mentioned special characters, the button events are firing in the page. Its happening only in my LIVE server, but not in my local. This has been happening from recently before everything was working fine, hope some of my DBAs has **changed/enabled** some configuration in IIS, but don't know what is that? Please, help.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
function ValidateFilegrid()
{
document.getElementById('<%=HidValid.ClientID %>').value = "";
var gridView = document.getElementById('<%=GVUploadedDocs.ClientID %>');
for (var i = 1; i < gridView.rows.length; i++)
{
     var radio = gridView.rows[i].getElementsByTagName('input');
     var selectedvalue;
     for (var j = 0; j < radio.length; j++)
     {
        if (radio[j].checked) 
        {
            selectedvalue = radio[j].value;
            break;
        }
    }
    var inputs2 = gridView.rows[i].getElementsByTagName('button')[0];
    if (selectedvalue != "Yes") 
    {
        var inputs = gridView.rows[i].getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
        if (inputs != null)
        {
            if(gridView.rows[i].getElementsByTagName('input')[1].value.length > 3)
            {
                if (inputs.value.length<3) 
                {
                    alert("Enter File Validation Remarks !!");
                    return false;
                }
                else
                {
                   document.getElementById('<%=HidValid.ClientID %>').value ="N";
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
return true;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Getting blocked...where? Are they posted to server with in a _plain_ form? Do you build "by hand" request to send them to server, for example, with Ajax?

Comment: We need more info: 1) Try it in chrome, note any JavaScript errors on the console, any failed network requests; and what the HTTP request looks like that fails; also, start logging things and share the code and the logging from the affected area. As your question is currently written, we'd be just as helpful throwing darts against a wall as we would be in trying to give you the correct answer.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker I debugged the code in Firefox using Firebug, but the method is running successful, up to its scope and returning true.  Please, see the Javascript code I posted above.

Comment: Hello every one no one is there in world to answer my question.........